# Google Stacked Bar Chart color

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

How can I change the color of the column in a stacked bar chart? If I specify the colors attribute in my MakeBarChart function, it only takes the first parameter. And makes the other columns a lighter version of that color. This is what it looks like;

[image]

And this is the code;

```html
function MakeBarChart(tmpData)
{ 
 var barArray = [];
 barArray.push(['', 'Open', 'Wachten', 'Opgelost']);
   for (key in tmpData) {
    if (tmpData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   barArray.push(['Week' + key, tmpData[key]['active'], tmpData[key]['waiting'], tmpData[key]['closed']])
    }
   }

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
  barArray
 );
 
 var options = {
  chart: {
  title: 'Incidenten per week',
  subtitle: '',
     'width':450,
     'height':300,
    },
    bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
  'backgroundColor':{ fill:'transparent' },
  isStacked: true,
  colors:['#000','#1111','#55555']
 };

 var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
 chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

How can I make the column all have their own separate color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your colors values, they are not in a correct RGB format.

Correct values will be :
either RGB hex values (with 2 digit hex value per color) like '#00CC88' or
either RGB hex values (with 1 digit hex value per color) like '#0C8' or
or a valid color name.

so instead of

```
colors:['#000','#1111','#55555'] // wrong values (2nd and 3rd values)
```

try

```
colors:['#11AA77','#999922','#550077']
```

or

```
colors:['#1A7','#992','#507']
```

or you can also do

```
colors:['red','darkgreen','yellow']
```

See a jsfiddle example here : https://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/2vjLc0q0/

Comment: Thanks! I've already switched it to a column graph but it is nice knowing it is possible as a bar too.