# How to change section color of a stacked bar chart in Google Charts API?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[The docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Colors) describe how to change the color of an entire bar by specifying a style data role column.

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
         ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
         ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
         ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
         ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
      ]);
```

Then, each record/item of the datatable can specify a color to represent itself.

But what if I am creating a stacked bar chart? Each record/item has multiple values for its different sections. How do I choose the colorings of each section (coloring based on columns/attributes), instead of choosing a color for each item record?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Stacked Bar Chart color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298669/google-stacked-bar-chart-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fiddle around with the *colors* configuration option:

```
columnChart.options = {
    ....
    colors: ['steelblue','orange','red']
     ...
```

}

The colors key is associated with an array where each string element specifies a color to be used to color the sections of a bar (the column attributes). Change the order around to achieve the desired section coloring.